# AWS API Gate Way with dotnet GRPC server side streaming

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, grpc, aws-api-gateway, grpc-dotnet

I am planning to use AWS APi Gate to in pair with dotnet GRPc HTTP2 protocol.

Before making the move I want to make sure AWS gateway will support all the features we already rely on.

One of the features we rely on is Server side streaming. Sample for server side streaming look something like this ins simplified version:

```
while (!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && i < 20)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500); // Gotta look busy
        
        var forecast = new WeatherData
        {
            DateTimeStamp = Timestamp.FromDateTime(now.AddDays(i++)),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        };
        // call that streams data to the client.
        await responseStream.WriteAsync(forecast);        
    }
```

I went over documentation for API gateway and I was unable to find it supports server side streaming.
If so, can someone point me to the documentation please where it describes what set up is needed for this or it is just been treated as a regular http request that will be transformed into HTTP2 request.

Thank you!